# Common JavaScript snippet to share files on Google Drive, Dropbox, Box.net or SkyDrive

Tags: jquery, dropbox, google-drive-api, code-snippets, onedrive

This is my first assignment of file sharing.

Need is to share files from our website to above mentioned locations.
Currently, I have been exploring each service’s API for file sharing.

**Question 1**: 
Is there any JavaScript code snippet available (like [addthis.com](http://www.addthis.com/)) to share files?

**Question 2**: Should I use server side coding for file sharing or JavaScript is advisable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks viewers. 
I found very useful plug-in named "Ink file picker". It saves given HTTP file resource directly into users online storage engine.

Url: https://developers.inkfilepicker.com/docs/web/

Live Example: http://ctrlq.org/save/